# Hibernate tutorials

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say that I'm new to Hibernate, is there a way to get my skills up to speed? Are there any good tutorials?

Comment: A video training course on Hibernate and JPA fundamentals has been released recently by http://mavenedge.com. See if you find that useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hibernate.org is pointing this to begin with :
[Getting Started  with Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/152.html)

I would then recommend reading this very good book  :
[Java Persistence with Hibernate (Christian Bauer and Gavin King)](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/)

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate.org's tutorial:

http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html

Depends though, are you just trying to get into Hibernate with no actual knowledge about what Hibernate is, or are just going to dive into the first tutorial you come across?

If you want a basic understanding of what Hibernate is, check out this link (very easy, short read):

http://www.laliluna.de/what-is-hibernate.html

They dumb it down enough for the layman who doesn't know anything (useful) about Hibernate to get a grasp on what it is and how it works.

Comment: I tried to use this tutorial, but their maven pom lacks version numbers, and will not build.  Also, they still use mapping files in it, not annotations.  Do you know of a more up to date & fully functional tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

There is J2EE course in Java Passion, which has a full [section](http://www.javapassion.com/j2ee/#Hibernate) about Hibernate.

Comment: Yep, you should definitely join that course, it's free and I'm on there too to help answer questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial with screen shots on how to set up hibernate in eclipse and creating first application. Go through this [hibernate tutorial](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2009/08/05/first-hibernate-tutorial-%E2%80%93get-hands-on-experience/)

If you are looking for something with read this [Hibernate JPA tutorial](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2009/08/06/hibernate-tutorial-continued-using-annotations/)