# Sample Hibernate Application for learning

Tags: java, hibernate

Can any one share some information about the sample application using hibernate for learning.
Basically I am looking for an application that allows me to do basic database operation from the client page.

Thanks,
Kamal

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate tutorials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650680/hibernate-tutorials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fllowing site will help you out.

http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/hibernate-tutorial.html

Lot of samples are available in net. google it.

Comment: hi Jothi,
I have seen hibernate tutorial, which uses JPA annotations and hibernate annotations. The tutorial which you have listed here is completely based on the hibernate config file.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [Hibernate 3.6.0.Beta4 release Announcement](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/Hibernate360Beta4Release)

Links to Getting Started Guide and Sample Applications are also available in the blog...

> Anyway, in the interm I thought this one was close enough that I went ahead and made it available from http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3636512/getting-started-guide/index.html. Some notes:
>       * This url is only made available temporarily
>       * The documentation references a link to obtain the code. That link is
>   not accurate. We are still deciding
>   where these will live and how they
>   will be referenced. In the meantime I
>   have zipped up the code and made it
>   available here:
>   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3636512/getting-started-guide/tutorials.tar.gz
>   (again temporarily).

Also Read `Java Persistence with Hibernate by Christian Bauer and Gavin King`. (bit old book but Excellent! :))