# Is there any object oriented way to use H2 database in java?

Tags: java, h2, object-oriented-database

I have a java application with embedded H2 database.

The H2 database library is said to be written completely in java. So there must be an object oriented equivalent for SQL statements like 'SELECT * FROM TABLE TESTTABLE' just like Table.select('*') etc...

Or is there any simple easy to use object oriented database library for java? As i'm developing a small application for registering book names, authors names, genres list etc... for a book library, speed is not a big concern.

Comment: This kind of object-oriented equivalent is an ORM (Hibernate, for instance). Note however that the most important part in ORM is the R, not the O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H2 is fundamentally an RDBMS (Relational Data Base Management System), so it's absolutely not "object oriented". It happens that its implementation is written with an object oriented language, namely Java, but it has strictly no consequence on its concepts.

That would similar to think that as you used a steel tool to shape a hammer in wood, the hammer is indeed steel...

As mentioned fge in its comment, to manipulate your database, currently managed by H2, in an object fashion, you need a specific library named ORM (for Object-Relational Mapping), for example http://www.hibernate.org/

Comment: Thanks for your help.. Could you please suggest me a good hibernate tutorial for beginners?

Comment: You can start with this entry in SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650680/hibernate-tutorials